# json_encode не полностью кодирует объект

Tags: php, json

Привет.
Есть объект:

```
SectionCalc::__set_state(array(
   'cpUnitParamsFile' => 'SectionParams',
   'paramsWhenICanChange' => 
  array (
    0 => 'supplySpecifyInput',
    1 => 'supplyAirInletTemp',
    2 => 'supplyAirInletHumidity',
    3 => 'exhaustSpecifyInput',
    4 => 'exhaustAirInletTemp',
    5 => 'exhaustAirInletHumidity',
  ),
   'freon' => NULL,
   'kmSections' => NULL,
   'sectionNum' => 2,
   'airDirection' => 'supply',
   'cvu_data' => 
  array (
    'cp_build_id' => '10555',
    'seria_id' => '38',
    'support_frame' => '1',
    'location' => 'vertical',
    'supply_air_stream' => 'bottom',
    'modesNames' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Летний',
    ),
    'alignStreams' => 'supply_begin',
    'roof' => '0',
    'sectionAlign' => NULL,
    'sections' => 
    array (
      'supply' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'sectionName' => 'VirtualUnit',
          'is_calculated' => true,
          'is_calculated_2' => false,
          'params_from_censuspaper' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'lAir' => '9000',
              'pFree' => '500',
              'airInletTemp' => '25',
              'airInletHumidity' => '60',
              'serviceSide' => 'right',
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => NULL,
              'GUID' => NULL,
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => NULL,
              'cvu_cpunits' => NULL,
            ),
          ),
          'params_for_calculation' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'lAir' => '9000',
              'pFree' => '500',
              'airInletTemp' => '25',
              'airInletHumidity' => '60',
              'serviceSide' => 'right',
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => NULL,
              'GUID' => NULL,
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => NULL,
              'cvu_cpunits' => NULL,
            ),
            'commonParams' => 
            array (
              'Vmin' => '2.5',
              'Vmax' => '3.5',
              'VminEx' => 1.8,
              'VmaxEx' => 5.2999999999999998,
              'Vmaxsupply' => '4',
              'Vmaxexhaust' => '4',
              'maxValueLAirSupply' => '9000',
              'maxValueLAirExhaust' => '9000',
            ),
          ),
          'calculation_result' => 
          array (
            'commonParams' => 
            array (
              'size' => '100',
              'velocitySupply' => 3.0499999999999998,
              'velocityExhaust' => 3.0499999999999998,
              'recommended' => true,
              'numCalcVariant' => 1,
              'checked' => false,
            ),
            0 => 
            array (
              'airInletL' => '9000',
              'airOutletL' => '9000',
              'airInletTemp' => '25',
              'airOutletTemp' => '25',
              'airInletHumidity' => '60',
              'airOutletHumidity' => '60',
              'airInletDryness' => 11.837374765368713,
              'airOutletDryness' => 11.837374765368713,
            ),
          ),
          'calculation_variants' => 
          array (
          ),
          'accumulated_params' => 
          array (
            'length' => 0,
            'weight' => 0,
            'height' => 0,
            'width' => 0,
            'airPressureDrop' => 0,
            'sectionName' => '',
          ),
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'sectionName' => 'SG.4',
          'is_calculated' => true,
          'is_calculated_2' => false,
          'params_from_censuspaper' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => '-1',
              'GUID' => '6403f765-c22c-9dee-8f15-eb7ad1fde15d',
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => 1,
              'cvu_cpunits' => 
              array (
                'supply' => 
                array (
                  '6403f765-c22c-9dee-8f15-eb7ad1fde15d' => '12',
                  '71013afb-31ca-8c28-ff1d-3d03ceb6cd12' => '36',
                  '26998124-d73f-757b-de10-a7640317b6e5' => '45',
                ),
                'exhaust' => 
                array (
                  '18e5d292-55b3-3638-2c83-53c43205d51e' => '12',
                  '6a52887b-6bf5-59e6-309d-553f34aeab53' => '45',
                  '5ee1ae42-48d6-132f-997b-33cfc6a13bb2' => '36',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          'params_for_calculation' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => '9000',
              'GUID' => '6403f765-c22c-9dee-8f15-eb7ad1fde15d',
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => 1,
              'cvu_cpunits' => 
              array (
                'supply' => 
                array (
                  '6403f765-c22c-9dee-8f15-eb7ad1fde15d' => '12',
                  '71013afb-31ca-8c28-ff1d-3d03ceb6cd12' => '36',
                  '26998124-d73f-757b-de10-a7640317b6e5' => '45',
                ),
                'exhaust' => 
                array (
                  '18e5d292-55b3-3638-2c83-53c43205d51e' => '12',
                  '6a52887b-6bf5-59e6-309d-553f34aeab53' => '45',
                  '5ee1ae42-48d6-132f-997b-33cfc6a13bb2' => '36',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          'calculation_result' => 
          array (
            'commonParams' => 
            array (
              'id' => '396',
              'seria_id' => '38',
              'size' => '100',
              'filter' => 'EG.4',
              'nomenclature_inserts' => 'S100/400 G4',
              'section_width' => '525',
              'section_height' => '930',
              'section_area' => '0.48825',
              'pocket_length' => '210',
              'number_of_pockets' => '4',
              'number_of_inserts' => '2',
              'filter_area' => '3.1248',
              'coefficient_of_resistance' => '160',
              'finite_resistance' => '250',
              'dimensions_length' => '280',
              'dimensions_width' => '1150',
              'dimensions_height' => '1035',
              'joining_width' => '850',
              'joining_height' => '715',
              'in_case' => '1',
              'weight' => '46',
              'pressostat' => '',
              'airVelocityMax' => 0.80005120327700974,
              'airPressureDropMax' => 102.4131084583986,
              'numCalcVariant' => 0,
            ),
            0 => 
            array (
              'airInletTemp' => '25',
              'airInletL' => '9000',
              'airInletHumidity' => '60',
              'airInletDryness' => 11.837374765368713,
              'airOutletTemp' => '25',
              'airOutletL' => '9000',
              'airOutletHumidity' => '60',
              'airOutletDryness' => 11.837374765368713,
              'airVelocity' => 0.80005120327700974,
              'air_pressure_drop' => 102.4131084583986,
            ),
          ),
          'calculation_variants' => 
          array (
          ),
          'accumulated_params' => 
          array (
            'length' => '280',
            'weight' => '46',
            'height' => '1035',
            'width' => '1150',
            'airPressureDrop' => 102.4131084583986,
            'sectionName' => 'EG.4',
          ),
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'sectionName' => 'SW.',
          'is_calculated' => false,
          'is_calculated_2' => false,
          'params_from_censuspaper' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'coating' => '0',
              'freonType' => 'R407C',
              'isApplied' => '1',
              'supplySpecifyInput' => '0',
              'supplyAirInletTemp' => NULL,
              'supplyAirInletHumidity' => NULL,
              'exhaustSpecifyInput' => NULL,
              'exhaustAirInletTemp' => NULL,
              'exhaustAirInletHumidity' => NULL,
              'airDesiredTemp' => '18',
              'equipment' => 'std',
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => '-1',
              'GUID' => '71013afb-31ca-8c28-ff1d-3d03ceb6cd12',
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => 2,
              'cvu_cpunits' => 
              array (
                'supply' => 
                array (
                  '6403f765-c22c-9dee-8f15-eb7ad1fde15d' => '12',
                  '71013afb-31ca-8c28-ff1d-3d03ceb6cd12' => '36',
                  '26998124-d73f-757b-de10-a7640317b6e5' => '45',
                ),
                'exhaust' => 
                array (
                  '18e5d292-55b3-3638-2c83-53c43205d51e' => '12',
                  '6a52887b-6bf5-59e6-309d-553f34aeab53' => '45',
                  '5ee1ae42-48d6-132f-997b-33cfc6a13bb2' => '36',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          'params_for_calculation' => 
          array (
          ),
          'calculation_result' => 
          array (
          ),
          'calculation_variants' => 
          array (
          ),
          'accumulated_params' => 
          array (
            'length' => 0,
            'weight' => 0,
            'height' => 0,
            'width' => 0,
            'airPressureDrop' => 0,
            'sectionName' => '',
          ),
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
          'sectionName' => 'SF.',
          'is_calculated' => false,
          'is_calculated_2' => false,
          'params_from_censuspaper' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'exhaustDirection' => 'directly',
              'engineType' => 'A',
              'powerReserve' => '10',
              'upwards_deviation' => NULL,
              'downward_deviation' => NULL,
              'method_of_selection' => NULL,
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => '-1',
              'GUID' => '26998124-d73f-757b-de10-a7640317b6e5',
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => 3,
              'cvu_cpunits' => 
              array (
                'supply' => 
                array (
                  '6403f765-c22c-9dee-8f15-eb7ad1fde15d' => '12',
                  '71013afb-31ca-8c28-ff1d-3d03ceb6cd12' => '36',
                  '26998124-d73f-757b-de10-a7640317b6e5' => '45',
                ),
                'exhaust' => 
                array (
                  '18e5d292-55b3-3638-2c83-53c43205d51e' => '12',
                  '6a52887b-6bf5-59e6-309d-553f34aeab53' => '45',
                  '5ee1ae42-48d6-132f-997b-33cfc6a13bb2' => '36',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          'params_for_calculation' => 
          array (
          ),
          'calculation_result' => 
          array (
          ),
          'calculation_variants' => 
          array (
          ),
          'accumulated_params' => 
          array (
            'length' => 0,
            'weight' => 0,
            'height' => 0,
            'width' => 0,
            'airPressureDrop' => 0,
            'sectionName' => '',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'exhaust' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'sectionName' => 'VirtualUnit',
          'is_calculated' => true,
          'is_calculated_2' => false,
          'params_from_censuspaper' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'lAir' => '9000',
              'pFree' => '400',
              'airInletTemp' => '25',
              'airInletHumidity' => '40',
              'serviceSide' => 'left',
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => NULL,
              'GUID' => NULL,
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => NULL,
              'cvu_cpunits' => NULL,
            ),
          ),
          'params_for_calculation' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'lAir' => '9000',
              'pFree' => '400',
              'airInletTemp' => '25',
              'airInletHumidity' => '40',
              'serviceSide' => 'left',
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => NULL,
              'GUID' => NULL,
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => NULL,
              'cvu_cpunits' => NULL,
            ),
          ),
          'calculation_result' => 
          array (
            'commonParams' => 
            array (
              'size' => '100',
              'velocitySupply' => 3.0499999999999998,
              'velocityExhaust' => 3.0499999999999998,
              'recommended' => true,
              'numCalcVariant' => 1,
              'checked' => false,
            ),
            0 => 
            array (
              'airInletL' => '9000',
              'airOutletL' => '9000',
              'airInletTemp' => '25',
              'airOutletTemp' => '25',
              'airInletHumidity' => '40',
              'airOutletHumidity' => '40',
              'airInletDryness' => 7.8915831769124773,
              'airOutletDryness' => 7.8915831769124773,
            ),
          ),
          'calculation_variants' => 
          array (
          ),
          'accumulated_params' => 
          array (
            'length' => 0,
            'weight' => 0,
            'height' => 0,
            'width' => 0,
            'airPressureDrop' => 0,
            'sectionName' => '',
          ),
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'sectionName' => 'SG.4',
          'is_calculated' => true,
          'is_calculated_2' => false,
          'params_from_censuspaper' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => '-1',
              'GUID' => '18e5d292-55b3-3638-2c83-53c43205d51e',
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => 1,
              'cvu_cpunits' => 
              array (
                'supply' => 
                array (
                  '6403f765-c22c-9dee-8f15-eb7ad1fde15d' => '12',
                  '71013afb-31ca-8c28-ff1d-3d03ceb6cd12' => '36',
                  '26998124-d73f-757b-de10-a7640317b6e5' => '45',
                ),
                'exhaust' => 
                array (
                  '18e5d292-55b3-3638-2c83-53c43205d51e' => '12',
                  '6a52887b-6bf5-59e6-309d-553f34aeab53' => '45',
                  '5ee1ae42-48d6-132f-997b-33cfc6a13bb2' => '36',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          'params_for_calculation' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => '9000',
              'GUID' => '18e5d292-55b3-3638-2c83-53c43205d51e',
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => 1,
              'cvu_cpunits' => 
              array (
                'supply' => 
                array (
                  '6403f765-c22c-9dee-8f15-eb7ad1fde15d' => '12',
                  '71013afb-31ca-8c28-ff1d-3d03ceb6cd12' => '36',
                  '26998124-d73f-757b-de10-a7640317b6e5' => '45',
                ),
                'exhaust' => 
                array (
                  '18e5d292-55b3-3638-2c83-53c43205d51e' => '12',
                  '6a52887b-6bf5-59e6-309d-553f34aeab53' => '45',
                  '5ee1ae42-48d6-132f-997b-33cfc6a13bb2' => '36',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          'calculation_result' => 
          array (
            'commonParams' => 
            array (
              'id' => '396',
              'seria_id' => '38',
              'size' => '100',
              'filter' => 'EG.4',
              'nomenclature_inserts' => 'S100/400 G4',
              'section_width' => '525',
              'section_height' => '930',
              'section_area' => '0.48825',
              'pocket_length' => '210',
              'number_of_pockets' => '4',
              'number_of_inserts' => '2',
              'filter_area' => '3.1248',
              'coefficient_of_resistance' => '160',
              'finite_resistance' => '250',
              'dimensions_length' => '280',
              'dimensions_width' => '1150',
              'dimensions_height' => '1035',
              'joining_width' => '850',
              'joining_height' => '715',
              'in_case' => '1',
              'weight' => '46',
              'pressostat' => '',
              'airVelocityMax' => 0.80005120327700974,
              'airPressureDropMax' => 102.4131084583986,
              'numCalcVariant' => 0,
            ),
            0 => 
            array (
              'airInletTemp' => '25',
              'airInletL' => '9000',
              'airInletHumidity' => '40',
              'airInletDryness' => 7.8915831769124773,
              'airOutletTemp' => '25',
              'airOutletL' => '9000',
              'airOutletHumidity' => '40',
              'airOutletDryness' => 7.8915831769124773,
              'airVelocity' => 0.80005120327700974,
              'air_pressure_drop' => 102.4131084583986,
            ),
          ),
          'calculation_variants' => 
          array (
          ),
          'accumulated_params' => 
          array (
            'length' => '280',
            'weight' => '46',
            'height' => '1035',
            'width' => '1150',
            'airPressureDrop' => 102.4131084583986,
            'sectionName' => 'EG.4',
          ),
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'sectionName' => 'SF.',
          'is_calculated' => false,
          'is_calculated_2' => false,
          'params_from_censuspaper' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'exhaustDirection' => 'directly',
              'engineType' => 'A',
              'powerReserve' => '10',
              'upwards_deviation' => NULL,
              'downward_deviation' => NULL,
              'method_of_selection' => NULL,
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => '-1',
              'GUID' => '6a52887b-6bf5-59e6-309d-553f34aeab53',
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => 2,
              'cvu_cpunits' => 
              array (
                'supply' => 
                array (
                  '6403f765-c22c-9dee-8f15-eb7ad1fde15d' => '12',
                  '71013afb-31ca-8c28-ff1d-3d03ceb6cd12' => '36',
                  '26998124-d73f-757b-de10-a7640317b6e5' => '45',
                ),
                'exhaust' => 
                array (
                  '18e5d292-55b3-3638-2c83-53c43205d51e' => '12',
                  '6a52887b-6bf5-59e6-309d-553f34aeab53' => '45',
                  '5ee1ae42-48d6-132f-997b-33cfc6a13bb2' => '36',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          'params_for_calculation' => 
          array (
          ),
          'calculation_result' => 
          array (
          ),
          'calculation_variants' => 
          array (
          ),
          'accumulated_params' => 
          array (
            'length' => 0,
            'weight' => 0,
            'height' => 0,
            'width' => 0,
            'airPressureDrop' => 0,
            'sectionName' => '',
          ),
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
          'sectionName' => 'SW.',
          'is_calculated' => false,
          'is_calculated_2' => false,
          'params_from_censuspaper' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'coating' => '0',
              'freonType' => NULL,
              'isApplied' => NULL,
              'supplySpecifyInput' => NULL,
              'supplyAirInletTemp' => NULL,
              'supplyAirInletHumidity' => NULL,
              'exhaustSpecifyInput' => '0',
              'exhaustAirInletTemp' => NULL,
              'exhaustAirInletHumidity' => NULL,
              'airDesiredTemp' => NULL,
              'equipment' => NULL,
              'lAirSpecifyInput' => '-1',
              'GUID' => '5ee1ae42-48d6-132f-997b-33cfc6a13bb2',
              'cpSeriesName' => NULL,
              'position' => 3,
              'cvu_cpunits' => 
              array (
                'supply' => 
                array (
                  '6403f765-c22c-9dee-8f15-eb7ad1fde15d' => '12',
                  '71013afb-31ca-8c28-ff1d-3d03ceb6cd12' => '36',
                  '26998124-d73f-757b-de10-a7640317b6e5' => '45',
                ),
                'exhaust' => 
                array (
                  '18e5d292-55b3-3638-2c83-53c43205d51e' => '12',
                  '6a52887b-6bf5-59e6-309d-553f34aeab53' => '45',
                  '5ee1ae42-48d6-132f-997b-33cfc6a13bb2' => '36',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          'params_for_calculation' => 
          array (
          ),
          'calculation_result' => 
          array (
          ),
          'calculation_variants' => 
          array (
          ),
          'accumulated_params' => 
          array (
            'length' => 0,
            'weight' => 0,
            'height' => 0,
            'width' => 0,
            'airPressureDrop' => 0,
            'sectionName' => '',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
   'calcSection' => 
  array (
    'sectionName' => 'SS.',
    'is_calculated' => false,
    'is_calculated_2' => false,
    'params_from_censuspaper' => 
    array (
      <params>
    ),
    'params_for_calculation' => 
    array (
    ),
    'calculation_result' => 
    array (
    ),
    'calculation_variants' => 
    array (
    ),
    'accumulated_params' => 
    array (
      'length' => 0,
      'weight' => 0,
      'height' => 0,
      'width' => 0,
      'airPressureDrop' => 0,
      'sectionName' => '',
    ),
  ),
   'cpSerie' => 
  CpSeries::__set_state(array(
     '_new' => false,
     '_attributes' => 
    array (
      'id' => '38',
      'unique_id' => 'SST',
      'series' => 'SST',
      'description' => 'SST',
      'Vmin' => '2.5',
      'Vmax' => '3.5',
      'shell_thickness' => '50',
      'support_frame' => '100',
      'dual_flow' => '1',
      'price_type' => 'SECTION',
      'brand' => '',
      'object' => '1',
      'module_type' => 'XS',
      'maxsmallsize' => '200',
      'v1' => '4',
      'v2' => '3.5',
      'v3' => '3.2',
      'v4' => '2.7',
      'heater_ds' => '-5',
      'cooler_ds' => '-2',
      'fan_ds' => 'E',
      'req_ds' => 'E',
      'alt_name_rule' => '0',
      'visible' => '1',
      'type' => 'sections',
      'roof' => '1',
      'sort' => '1',
      'select_rule' => '1',
      'aut_select_rule' => '1',
      'draw_rule' => '1',
      'supply_allow' => '1',
      'exhaust_allow' => '1',
      'isolation_material' => '',
      'external_sheet' => '',
      'internal_sheet' => '',
      'base_execution' => '',
      'end_panel' => '1',
    ),
     '_related' => 
    array (
    ),
     '_c' => NULL,
     '_pk' => '38',
     '_alias' => 't',
     '_errors' => 
    array (
    ),
     '_validators' => NULL,
     '_scenario' => 'update',
     '_e' => NULL,
     '_m' => NULL,
  )),
   'airDirections' => 
  array (
    0 => 'supply',
    1 => 'exhaust',
  ),
   'calculationVariants' => NULL,
   'errors' => 
  array (
  ),
   'warnings' => 
  array (
  ),
   'activeFormWidget' => NULL,
   'params' => 
  array (
  ),
   'paramsAndAttributes' => 
  array (
  ),
   'isCalculated' => false,
))
```

При кодировании с помощью json_encode теряется большая часть данных:

```
{
    "calcSection": {
        "sectionName": "SS.",
        "is_calculated": false,
        "is_calculated_2": false,
        "params_from_censuspaper": [
            {
                <params>
            }
        ],
        "params_for_calculation": {
            "commonParams": {
                "coating": "0",
                "freonType": "R407C"
            },
            "0": {
                "coating": "0",
                "freonType": "R407C",
                "isApplied": "1",
                "supplySpecifyInput": "0",
                "supplyAirInletTemp": "25",
                "supplyAirInletHumidity": "60",
                "exhaustSpecifyInput": "0",
                "exhaustAirInletTemp": "25",
                "exhaustAirInletHumidity": "40",
                "airDesiredTemp": "18",
                "equipment": "std",
                "supplyLAirSpecifyInput": "-1",
                "GUID": "71013afb-31ca-8c28-ff1d-3d03ceb6cd12",
                "cpSeriesName": null,
                "position": 2,
                "cvu_cpunits": {
                    "supply": {
                        "6403f765-c22c-9dee-8f15-eb7ad1fde15d": "12",
                        "71013afb-31ca-8c28-ff1d-3d03ceb6cd12": "36",
                        "26998124-d73f-757b-de10-a7640317b6e5": "45"
                    },
                    "exhaust": {
                        "18e5d292-55b3-3638-2c83-53c43205d51e": "12",
                        "6a52887b-6bf5-59e6-309d-553f34aeab53": "45",
                        "5ee1ae42-48d6-132f-997b-33cfc6a13bb2": "36"
                    }
                },
                "exhaustLAirSpecifyInput": "-1",
                "supplyAirInletDryness": 11.837374765369,
                "exhaustAirInletDryness": 7.8915831769125,
                "supplyLAir": "9000",
                "exhaustLAir": "9000"
            }
        },
        "calculation_result": [
        ],
        "calculation_variants": [
        ],
        "accumulated_params": {
            "length": 0,
            "weight": 0,
            "height": 0,
            "width": 0,
            "airPressureDrop": 0,
            "sectionName": ""
        }
    },
    "calculationVariants": null,
    "isCalculated": false
}
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: видимо в том, что у объекта есть поля с областью видимости `private`?

Comment: покажите еще var_dump() объекта перед тем как вы его передаете в json_encode()